# How to Execute a method once when the event triggers very first time?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have this following Event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            sPort = new SerialPort();
            sPort.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
            sPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox5.Text);
            sPort.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.Text);
            sPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), comboBox2.Text);
            sPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), comboBox4.Text);
            sPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            sPort.RtsEnable = true;
            sPort.DtrEnable = true;
            sPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sPort_datareceived);

            sPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK.ToString());
        }
    }

     private void sPort_datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {                
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        datain = sp.ReadExisting();                
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(idextraction));
    }

    public string namingid;

    private void idextraction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Match matchid = Regex.Match(datain, @"\b\d{12}\b");
        namingid = matchid.Value;
        namingid = namingid.Substring(namingid.Length - 7);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(writesyncdata));
    }

 private void writesyncdata(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\intdata\\" + namingid + ".txt");
            tw.Write(datain);
            tw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Suppose this Event triggers X No. of times and then stops and then Triggers Again And the Cycle Goes On. The Time Interval is between 1-2 sec when the event triggers X no. of times. I want to Invoke My method once the very first time the event triggers and stop afterwards but My method should Execute once every time the Cycle Starts.

When idextraction() invokes it doesn't work because the data in buffer is less to process(it takes 1-2 sec to fill full data but my method invokes before that and that's the problem)

I Know the how to execute a method once but as the event triggers many times in short period of time so my method also and i don't want that. Does anybody know how to do it ?

Comment: Show where you've wired up the serial port event. There's not enough context to know what the problem is.

Comment: Actually, it's an HIS instrument whenever the user transmits data from other side the cycle starts and it takes around 1-3 sec(Depends on Baud rate) to end the Cycle.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer you question. Most people read all the data off the port whenever the event fires so they don't have this problem.

Comment: this is the only event where i process the data when it fires. when this event fires i process data and save into txt file. while processing when mymethod requires 2000

Comment: You need to share the rest of the code

Comment: ok i will share my rest of the code

Comment: I have updated my question and shared my code. please ask ask if u don't understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the event fires, you have no idea how much information will be available. It is your responsibility to buffer up all the data as it is received until you have something useful to do with it. There are a variety of ways to do this, like you could have a queue of bytes. When data is received, you add the data to the end of the queue and check if it is enough to process it. If it is, the call your processing routine. If it is not, then wait for more data to be received. You will need a separate queue for each serial port you open.

Comment: Exactly How do i wait for my method to be executed after all the data has been received in the buffer ? and How do check if it is enough to process using the sam event ?

Comment: It depends entirely on what the data is. You have to inspect it yourself and decide when you have enough to do what you need to do. Imagine you were processing one big array of characters. How would you do it? You'll need to do something similar. You can do it all in the event handler: add newly received data in the buffer, check if you have enough data to process, remove and process the data if you have enough.